# zeroMQ: zmq_recv() doesn't work

Tags: c++, zeromq, recv

I am using zeroMQ to realize the send-recv message. I use this pattern: PUB-SUB.
However, it seems that I can send some message from the publisher but I couldn't receive it from the subscriber. Here is my code:

//subscriber:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    void * context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void * subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp:://127.0.0.1:5556");
    const int SIZE = 20;
    char msg[SIZE];
    cout<<"receiving..."<<endl;
    cout<<zmq_recv(subscriber, msg, SIZE, 0)<<endl;
    cout<<"received";
    zmq_close(subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

//publisher:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    void * context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void * publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5556");
    srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));
    char updateMsg[20] = "hello world";
    while(1)
    {
        cin.get();
        cout<<"sending..."<<endl;
        cout<<zmq_send(publisher, updateMsg, 20, 0)<<endl;
        cout<<"sent"<<endl;
    }
    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I run the publisher then I run the subscriber.
Then I type "Enter" at the publisher and it says:

```
sending...
20
sent<l
```

BUT, at the subscriber, it always shows only this line: `receiving...`
It seems that `zmq_recv()` is blocked.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Rather than edit the question, here on StackOverflow it's better if you post an answer to your own question and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the PUB-SUB pattern, we MUST use `setsockopt` to set a filter for the subscriber. Otherwise, the subscriber can't receive ANY message. So for this case, what we should do is to add the code below for the subscriber before the `zmq_recv`:
`zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "hello", strlen("hello"));`

Answer (score 1):

http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5#Pros-and-Cons-of-Pub-Sub

says:

> Publishers can't tell when subscribers are successfully connected, both on initial connections, and on reconnections after network failures.

The point here is that your publisher is started first, sends its messages into the void, as fast as possible to your hardware.

In the meantime, your subscriber fails, because your URL contains one `:` too many, or something else:

```
zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp:://127.0.0.1:5556");
```

so here you go: an infinite amount of messages being sent nowhere, and failed subscriber that doesn't tell you it's failed, as well as a publisher not noticing the receiving end hasn't successfully connected.

Comment: that's why I wrote "*or something else*"; you will have check the success of the `connect` command, like the zeroMQ documentation says.

Comment: I detected the return value of `zmq_connect` here and I got 0. So I think it connected successfully. In fact I code on my server, most of the ports are closed by the firewall. Could it be the reason why I cant receive the message? I dont know the server very well. Closing the ports means the program cant even receive the local message?

Comment: problem solved~~~~ It's because we must use `setsockopt` for the subscriber to set a filter. Otherwise, the subscriber can't get any message.

Answer (score 1):

### A: ZeroMQ does work.

### Your code is OK,

### while you have missed a conceptually important point in `PUB-SUB` design

Yes, ZeroMQ does work well.
Yes, your code is OK, so **where is the trouble?**

The **`PUB-SUB`** **Formal Communication Pattern** has been designed so that  `PUB`/publisher-side distributes each and every message just to those `SUB`/subscriber-side(s), that have presented themselves to the `PUB` their individual **will-to-receive** something. This is being done by so called subscription ( so natural in our human world -- you do not receive any newspapers you have not subscribed to and you may receive some of the papers, you have ).

The ZeroMQ design mirrors this natural pattern.

A "new"-`SUB` is assumed as not ( implicitly ) subscribed to anything.

Any `SUB` may subscribe to receive just messages that meet a specified "subscription".

Any `SUB` may subscribe to receive "everything".

So your code was running as declared - both on the `PUB` side ( sending nothing to an active `SUB` side, that just has not yet presented any will to receive something, that thus receives nothing at all, still sitting in a [***blocking***] waiting-state ).

**Nota bene**: you might benefit a lot from an excellent book from Pieter HINTJENS -- "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" (available in PDF), where Pieter spends a lot of time explaining conceptual thinking behind this great, smart, scaleable, nonblocking messaging library. Definitely worth spend a few weeks on his text ( not the code-snippets, but the stories hidden there ). **A marvelous book, indeed.**